# Upgrading from Blazor 7 to Blazor 8 - OnAfterRenderAsync is not getting triggered

Tags: blazor

I am upgrading a Blazor 7.0 Server App to Blazor 8.0 Web App. I created a new project under the Blazor 8.0 Web App, using Interactive Server and copied my files there, per Microsoft's guidelines. Now, when executing my code, neither OnAfterRender nor OnAfterRenderAsync are getting triggered, which is needed for JS interop. I validated this with breakpoints at the start of the method.

Relevent parts of the Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

In App, I tried adding `@rendermode="InteractiveServer"` to the `Routes` as well, with no change.

I've searched here and on Google and have yet to find the answer. Even Microsoft's site isn't clear. From what I've seen through learn.microsoft.com, it looks like I should be working.

Comment: All the interactive modes include SSR first.  The Rendermode attributes have a parameter to control this, which defaults to true. You need to declare a static class of the rendermode with the param set to false.

Comment: It is my understanding that I want prerendering to be true, at least that was the case in 7.0. Also, when I set `@rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)"` on `<Routers>` in App, the site doesn't load at all, and I don't even hit my breakpoint for OnInitialized. Unless I'm misunderstanding, what you mentioned about the static class Microsoft says isn't necessary except to reduce verbocity (which actually makes it more verbose, I think). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-shorthand-render-modes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. It turns out I accidentally removed the blazor.web script from my App.

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
```

Once that was readded and I added `@rendermode="InteractiveServer"` to my `<Routes>` my breakpoint was getting hit as expected.